# Word and IE (Close Word needs to Refresh IE)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, ms-word

I am able to open Word with a specific template from the browser, but when Word closes and the user returns to the browser the page needs to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

that's a hard one - but there is an open-source framework you can download, which has such functionality. [re-motion](http://www.re-motion.org/) and you need to use the DMS component.